# Configure Fluent API in EF Core for nested Classes

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core with Asp Net Core.

There is a `User.cs` class I have

```
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

and there is a `Contact.cs` class

```
public class Contact
{
   
   public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

So here is my builder

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);            
          
            builder.Entity<User>().OwnsOne(x => x.Contact);
         }
```

So my question is about **"How can I set my Contact(nested in User) may have a list of PhoneNumber objects"?**
I want all is that everything stored in one table, question is not about storing multiple phonenumbers per user.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#collections-of-primitives

Comment: "everything stored in one table" is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to. You can simply go ahead and declare it. As you can see here EF Core is "[smart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#conventions)". It recognizes its a navigation property.

Simply declaring your classes will do it for you. If you put in a list it will automatically catch it in the schema and create it.

You FluentAPI doesn't need the OwnsOne as well unless you want to enforce it if possible but this depends on the DB.

```
builder.Entity<Contact>().HasMany(x => x.PhoneNumbers); // does nothing new. Maybe you want for clarity or if you want extra configurations
```

Now how do you retrieve all of them for a user?

With `Select` no need for JSON conversion:

`users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id = "random_id").Select(u => u.Contact.PhoneNumbers)`

Make sure your classes have ID properties for the navigation. For example your `Contact.cs` will have an invisible UserId column in the database but you wont have it in code. This is not required but its a good practice. Or even better add a `User` property on `Contact`.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the list of `PhoneNumbers` serialized as JSON in the table. EF Core allows you to perform this serialization & deserializion seamlessly using **Value Conversion**s.

Using [Microsoft's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#collections-of-primitives) as reference:

```cs
builder.Entity<User>()
    .Property(e => e.PhoneNumbers)
    .HasConversion(
        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<PhoneNumber>>(v, null),
        new ValueComparer<ICollection<PhoneNumber>>(
            (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
            c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
            c => (ICollection<PhoneNumber>)c.ToList()));
```

### Further info

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 1):

If your PhoneNumber object doesn't store any additional values apart from the phone number, you could store it as multiple string values, separated by a common delimiter:

```
public class Contact
{   
   public string[] PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .Property(e => e.PhoneNumbers)
            .HasConversion(
                v => string.Join(';', v),
                v => v.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Else if PhoneNumber has multiple values, I'd go for JSON serialization/deserialization as per @abdusco's answer.